# Relatório Dinâmico c#

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, relatório

Estou a preparar um relatório com a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom até o momento está configurado tudo certo, estou utilizando C# Windows Form, utilizando o componente ReportViewer para fazer o relatório, porém na hora de obter os dados, ele pega apenas as informações do primeiro registro, queria que gerasse um registro desse por página, com as informações para cada dado especificado na linha, isto tendo um botão também acima para listar somente os dados de certos eventos em certas cidades.

Estou num ponto que não sei como colocar isso em código e também não daria certo de colocar isso numa table, matrix ou list.

Gostaria de saber como fazer tal quebra de pagina para cada registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom Consegui, se alguém quiser dar como respondido.
Fiz do seguinte método:

Para conseguir mostrar todos os registros é necessário ter um 'data region' (table, list ou matrix).
Ai apenas criei uma table mesmo com 3 linhas e 1 coluna, e organizei como se fosse meus 3 caixa de texto, e depois nas propriedades static deixei que ouvesse a quebra de página. Assim repetindo em todas páginas com todos os registros e opções de filtragem.

Grato a quem pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

@SNOT, você tem que utilizar o "Header" para colocar o conteúdo ou o "[Nome]", e os outros itens na "SubTotal", e configurar o relatório para efetuar a quebra por nome, já que a sua consulta está passando os campos Nome, LocalEnvento, data_hora_evento.

A "Body" você pode deixar em branco, não lembro se a excluir irá funcionar, mas vale testar.

att

LMV

Suponha que você tenha o seguinte:
[NOME]-----------[data_hora_evento]---------[localEvento]----[sala]
Luiz Marcelo.......2015-07-01 09:00..........Hotel xyz......sala 1
Luiz Marcelo.......2015-07-01 10:00..........Hotel xyz......sala 2
Francisco M........2015-07-01 09:00..........Hotel xyz......sala 1
Francisco M........2015-07-01 10:00..........Hotel xyz......sala 2

Mas você não quer a sala, então você utiliza o recurso da subtotal, que irá indicar somente um [NOME] e [LocalEvento].

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem, como funciona a questão de colocar eles na subtotal?

Comment: @SNOT, vamos lá, no relatório é criado um cabeçalho, o corpo do relatório e o total e para complementar, pode acrescentar outras estruturas como o sub-total.
Assim se você ocultar o corpo do relatório (body) terá o Cabçalho (header) , e o SubTotal. Colocando a quebra de página no subtotal quando exibir será impresso em cada página, o cabeçalho, o Subtotal, modelo que você deseja. 

Se persistir a dúvida te mando um modelo a noite, pois estou no trabalho e não tenho como fazer no momento.

Comment: @SNOT, de uma olhada, fiz uma busca rápida https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Gerando-relatrios-com-815c3396

Comment: bom esse exemplo é muito básico e não serviria, até porque no modo como mostrei, não está usando tabela, para obter todos os valores referente aquilo. Como seria um dado por página ele não consegue reconhecer que tem outros e mandar pra próxima pagina, nem tanto a quebra de página como o método de fazer no cabeçalho estão dando certo